# Rails Secret API Keys storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api-key

I'm using Rails 5.2 right now, and I'm trying to enter a couple of API keys for production purposes. But when I run `EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit`, I get an error message of below:

[image]

What do I need to do in order to open a text editor to store the production API keys?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have already not save any credentials than please remove your credentials keys

```
rm config/master.key
rm config/master.key
```

Now try it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `config/credentials.yml.enc` file:

```
rm config/credentials.yml.enc
```

and then run:

```
EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit
```

This should solve the issue.